# How to debug CSS3 3d transformations in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, animation, 3d

I want to create an animated information bar with CSS3 3D-animations based on the idea of [this](http://zerosixthree.se/snippets/css-3d-link-hover-effect/) post.

I was able to recreate the same behaviour which works on Chrome, Firefox and Opera but not in IE: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JXcHc/)

Now I'm wondering that if there is any way to fix this animation to work in IE too - at least in IE 11?

(The original sample also doesn't work in IE.)

The main trick of this 3D-effect is that you have to create two elements - in this case two `span` elements - which are perpendicular to each other, and then on some "event" (on a hover or on some change) you rotate the wrapper of these elements by 90 degree:

```
#info.change #msgWrapper {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, -30px) rotateX(90deg);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, -30px) rotateX(90deg);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, -30px) rotateX(90deg);
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, -30px) rotateX(90deg);
}
```

In IE it looks like that this rotation works but the initial layout is wrong.
Unfortunately it is very hard to debug, because the only thing that I can see in the developer toolbar is the transformation matrix - which looks correct...

Any idea on how to fix this stuff to work in IE?

Answer (score 0):

see this Pages :
[IE Transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673529%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[3D Hands](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/hands-on-css3/hands-on_3d-transforms.htm)

Maybe Help you...